# How to automate content deletion and updation in a webpage

Tags: web, automation, frontend, content-management-system, icalendar

I am new to frontend development. My question is -
How to automate deleting an event section in a webpage once the event is post date?
How to automate generating ics links for google and apple calendar for these events.

For now, I am doing it manually by updating the source code.